# Knapsack problem with incompatibility, Help with AMPL

Tags: optimization, binary-programming

I have a fairly straight forward problem. I have to like solve the knapsack problem with incompatibility.

The way I have set the problem up is:

[Problem setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uX4rR.png)

Meaning that item i and j can not be included at the same time.

This is the mod.file
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKKeE.png)

When I upload it to Neos I get this error message.

amplin, line 30 (offset 306):
    syntax error
context:   >>> var  <<< x{i in 1..n}  binary;

I don't quite understand why it does not read x as a variable.

Thanks

Edit: I would like someone to help me understand why I get the error message when I upload my AMPL file to Neos.

Comment: "I have to like solve the knapsack problem with incompatibility." You mean you want someone to make you like solving the problem ? If so, here's a link to a Knapsack video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5jIfgETYKRE

Comment: I would like someone to help me with figuring out why I get the error message that it doesnt understand "var".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a terminating semicolon for the previous "param" statement.

Also, your incomp constraint has a superfluous sum operator.

By the way, incompatibility like this is usually modeled with a "conflict" constraint $x_i + x_j \le 1$ for each bad pair $i<j$.

Comment: Hi, I added the semicolon, though now I get the mistake
amplin, line 45 (offset 550):
 syntax error
context:  sum {i  >>> in  <<< 1..n} x[i] + x[j] >= M[i,j] * m;
About the constraint regular formulation about the constraint, if I were just to write a constraint that said x_i+x_j wouldn't that mean that I couldn't include 2 items at once ?

I have been given a matrix, which has entry 1 if the items cannot be included at the same time and 0 if they can. That is why I used the big M constraint.

Thanks btw.

Comment: Yes, see the second sentence I added to my answer.

Comment: I am not sure that I understand.

Comment: In the incomp constraint, you are using i as both a constraint index and a summation index.  You can't do both, and the sum should not be there.

Comment: If I remove the sum over i and remove it from the constraint, like this :

subject to incomp {j in 1..n} : 

x[i] + x[j] >= M[i,j] * m;

I get the error message:    i is not defined
context:   >>> x[i] <<<  + x[j] >= M[i,j] *

Comment: Image on new constraint : https://imgur.com/a/qaSzHlr

Comment: You should remove the sum {i in 1..n} only.

Comment: Like this ? https://imgur.com/a/XN3l035  

I get an error message presolve: constraint incomp[15,13] cannot hold:
 body >= 10 cannot be <= 2; difference = 8

Comment: https://imgur.com/cqumRUb I added the M[i,j] Matrix

Comment: Please post the code as text instead of images and in the question instead of the comments.  And please clarify what M[i,j] represents.

Comment: I have solved the problem, thanks to your comment about not using i as both a summation and constraint index. Thank you for your time I really appreciate it, I will make sure to make a comprehensive post about my problem next time. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad to help, but I suspect that you want this: subject to incomp {i in 1..n, j in 1..n: i < j and M[i,j] = 1}: x[i] + x[j] <= 1;

Comment: M[i,j] is the matrix that determines whether or not you can include the items at once, if M[i,j]=1 then you cant include item i and j in the pack at the same time. I used: subject to incomp {i in 1..n,j in 1..n} : 

x[i] + x[j] + M[i,j] <= 2;

I am not sure why I need the i<j and I dont know what M[i,j]=1 means (especially in the constraint.)

Comment: What you wrote just now is correct but inefficient in two ways: 1. Because M[i,j] is symmetric, you have duplicate constraints (i < j and i > j yield the same constraint), and 2. When M[i,j] = 0, the constraint is redundant, so you might as well not impose it.  When M[i,j] = 1, your constraint reduces to what I suggested.

Comment: So both mine and yours can be used to reach the correct answer, mine is just more computationally heavy because it checks both triangles of the matrix to see if the constraints are not being violated ?

Comment: Yes, both are correct.  You should notice that the presolver removes most of your constraints.

Comment: Yea, I just ran yours and compared it to mine and I get the message that 199 constraints has been removed by the presolver. The presolver fine tunes my problem before Neos solves it ?
Thanks for that clarification.